# Does this bug indicate an error in my btrfs filesystem of simply a bug in the 4.2.0-RC5 kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, btrfs

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this...

I have been running a pre-release kernel (4.2.0-rc5) and yesterday had a possible disk error on my 6-disk raid-1 btrfs filesysystem. While trying to execute the command `btrfs device remove ...` I repeatedly got a kernel bugcheck which logged the message `kernel BUG at fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c:1833!`.

```
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: kernel BUG at fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c:1833!
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: Modules linked in: nfsd nfs_acl rpcsec_gss_krb5 auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfsv4 dns_resolver nfs lockd grace sunrpc fscache qt1010 af9013 dvb_usb_af9015 dvb_usb_v2 dvb_core rc_core sp5100_tco kvm_amd kvm pcspkr snd_hda_codec_hdmi evdev amd64_edac_mod edac_mce_amd edac_core nvidia(PO) i2c_piix4 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core sg snd_hwdep snd_pcm tpm_infineon tpm_tis tpm snd_timer snd soundcore drm acpi_cpufreq processor thermal_sys button shpchp md_mod k10temp jc42 i2c_core loop parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic btrfs xor raid6_pq dm_mod hid_generic usbhid hid sd_mod usb_storage ohci_pci tg3 ptp pps_core libphy ahci libahci libata ehci_pci ohci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod usbcore usb_common
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 95 Comm: kworker/u8:7 Tainted: P           O    4.2.0-rc5-derek-00033-g6c84461-dirty #5
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: Hardware name: HP ProLiant MicroServer, BIOS O41     10/01/2013
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: Workqueue: btrfs-extent-refs btrfs_extent_refs_helper [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: task: ffff880213b8cd00 ti: ffff880213b90000 task.ti: ffff880213b90000
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa020e4b3>]  [<ffffffffa020e4b3>] insert_inline_extent_backref+0xe3/0xf0 [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff880213b93af8  EFLAGS: 00010293
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000001
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: RDX: ffff880000000000 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 0000000000000000
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: RBP: ffff8800daef2800 R08: 0000000000004000 R09: ffff880213b93a08
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000003 R12: ffff8801d797dad0
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: R13: 0000000000004b18 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00001c7de0f8c000
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: FS:  00007fab947cb8c0(0000) GS:ffff88021fc80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: CR2: 00000000010928d8 CR3: 00000000aa465000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: Stack:
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  00001c7de0f8c000 0000000000004b18 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  0000000000000001 0000000000000282 ffff8801d797dad0 ffffffffa020f9c0
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  ffff880213b93bb4 00000000000034bd ffff8801d797dae0 ffff8800db81b000
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: Call Trace:
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffffa020f9c0>] ? __btrfs_free_extent.isra.68+0x320/0xd50 [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffffa020e927>] ? __btrfs_inc_extent_ref.isra.52+0xa7/0x280 [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffffa0273fb2>] ? find_ref_head+0x52/0x70 [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffffa0213ce1>] ? __btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0xc41/0x1070 [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff8101c6a5>] ? sched_clock+0x5/0x10
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff811b9292>] ? __sb_start_write+0x42/0xe0
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffffa0216c81>] ? btrfs_run_delayed_refs.part.73+0x71/0x270 [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff8109aef0>] ? update_curr+0xb0/0xf0
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffffa0216f18>] ? delayed_ref_async_start+0x78/0x90 [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffffa0259bb0>] ? btrfs_scrubparity_helper+0xc0/0x280 [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff81083401>] ? process_one_work+0x1a1/0x430
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff810836d7>] ? worker_thread+0x47/0x4a0
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff81083690>] ? process_one_work+0x430/0x430
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff810890f1>] ? kthread+0xc1/0xe0
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff81089030>] ? kthread_worker_fn+0x170/0x170
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff81539b9f>] ? ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  [<ffffffff81089030>] ? kthread_worker_fn+0x170/0x170
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: Code: 89 d9 4c 89 34 24 4d 89 e8 4c 89 f9 4c 89 e6 48 89 ef 48 89 44 24 10 8b 84 24 a8 00 00 00 89 44 24 08 e8 f1 d6 ff ff 31 c0 eb b3 <0f> 0b 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 56 41 
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: RIP  [<ffffffffa020e4b3>] insert_inline_extent_backref+0xe3/0xf0 [btrfs]
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel:  RSP <ffff880213b93af8>
Aug 15 10:42:44 capella kernel: ---[ end trace 1cdbb5a82e302412 ]---
```

Looking at the source code, the relevent function was `int insert_inline_extent_backref(...)` which called `lookup_inline_extent_backup(...)`; presumably, this returned zero so line 1833 `BUG_ON(owner < BTRFS_FIRST_FREE_OBJECTID)` was executed.

```
static noinline_for_stack
int insert_inline_extent_backref(struct btrfs_trans_handle *trans,
                 struct btrfs_root *root,
                 struct btrfs_path *path,
                 u64 bytenr, u64 num_bytes, u64 parent,
                 u64 root_objectid, u64 owner,
                 u64 offset, int refs_to_add,
                 struct btrfs_delayed_extent_op *extent_op)
{
    struct btrfs_extent_inline_ref *iref;
    int ret;

    ret = lookup_inline_extent_backref(trans, root, path, &iref,
                       bytenr, num_bytes, parent,
                       root_objectid, owner, offset, 1);
    if (ret == 0) {
        BUG_ON(owner < BTRFS_FIRST_FREE_OBJECTID);
        update_inline_extent_backref(root, path, iref,
                         refs_to_add, extent_op, NULL);
    } else if (ret == -ENOENT) {
        setup_inline_extent_backref(root, path, iref, parent,
                        root_objectid, owner, offset,
                        refs_to_add, extent_op);
        ret = 0;
    }
    return ret;
```

}

This occurred repeatedly using the RC5 kernel, so I tried the Debian 4.1.0-1 amd64 release, which completed the device remove successfully.

Obvious question: is this something corrupt in my filesystem which the earlier kernel misses, or is it just a bug in the 4.2.0-RC5 version which will hopefully be fixed in the final release?

I've run a scrub of the data which reported no errors. Is there anything else I should check?

FYI: I initially downloaded the source, built and ran a pre-release kernel when I wanted to convert the data on a filesystem and found that `btrfs balance start -dconvert=RAID1 ...` command was broken in the released version!

Comment: You should report it & let kernel developers decide what to make of it. (If no one reports it, probably it won't be fixed.)

Comment: Already reported to SuSE. https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=940212

Comment: @frostschutz: For future reference, where's the best place to report btrfs kernel bugs? Opensuse wouldn't be an obvious choice to me.

Comment: Your distro's bugtracker (when using official kernels of your distro); the btrfs mailing list, or if in doubt the LKML or kernel bugtracker. Try the latest -rc first (maybe it was fixed in rc6 already?), and check (with Google) for already existing reports of the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Btrfs 4.2, here is someone who is getting a similar error message:

```
kernel BUG at fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c:1833!
```

https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg47782.html

According to the response, they're already working on a patch:

https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg47783.html

Generally, bugs can be reported on [bugzilla on kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=btrfs). There does not appear to be a bug report for this crash.

So your filesystem should be fine, especially since the scrub found no error.

If someone is having the same issue at some point, it might be an idea to use a live system like Parted Magic or an install disc (like Debian which you used) with an older kernel to mount the filesystem and perform the balance that doesn't work with the newer version.

Comment: I generally have 2 or 3 previous kernels available to boot from as well as a USB stick with a live CD available. Hence my note about booting version 4.1.0-1 amd64.